# Computers stopped working after a month of inactivity

Tags: boot

I have two computers that are located about five feet away from a window, a Mac laptop and a Dell mini tower. Recently I was away for about a month. I disconnected both computers from the outlet. When I returned neither computer would turn on. I don't hear any noise, see any led or sny indication that something is happening. As far as I can tell, no rain or wetness occurred. The temperature never went beliw or even close to freezing. What could have happened to them? Is there something I can do to fix them?

I've tried charging the laptop for a few hours, and I've tried a long push on the Dell's power button to discharge static electricity.

Comment: Take them to a local repair shop. It is impossible to say with any accuracy based on the above. Drives can stick but not usually after a month. Humidity could be an issue.

Comment: Also check your power outlet as it may have clicked off.

Comment: The outlet definitely works - the monitors are working fine.

Comment: So take the computers to the shop and see what is wrong.

Comment: don't underestimate how odd power outlet and power supply issues can be. Try them on another outlet just to be sure. i once worked on a very dead PC for a relative, and just bringing it into another room fixed the issue. it helped to learn that they had returned 3 PCs before that. PCs can be sensitive to dirty power in ways other appliances aren't. there are ways for outlets to be bad that don't necessarilly affect all devices.

Comment: Did you check the power supply switch?  Pretty easy to forget after a month and something I might do if powering off for awhile.